# Setting up a server over the internet

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, remote-installation

I have a client who wants me to set up Ubuntu server on his machine over the internet. I am a front end developer but am pretty comfortable using linux. Is there a way to do this, perhaps SSH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this up via SSH if his system is configured correctly to accept this type of connection and you are able to configure the system via a terminal. You could also use a remote desktop tool like [Teamviewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) if you prefer a graphical view of the system.

In order to configure SSH you/client would need to do something like:

1. `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` - Install ssh
2. `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config` - Specify the listening port within this file
3. `sudo service ssh restart` - Restart SSH
4. Set up a router rule to send ssh connections on that port to the desired system (you get the internal system internal IP using `ifconfig`)

Something like this will work fine for a simple SSH connection.

If you want specifics on setup you would need to tell us what type of server the client is after. I assume from tags it is a web server, but is there a preference on installation or will apache be enough for the desired outcome?

Comment: Thanks, I have used SSH before and was thinking that this is the proper way to do so. You cleared my doubt

Comment: @Bazinga777 | I use SSH to configure my web server. No issues. If this is a usable method for you it is a perfectly acceptable method of doing this type of configuration. Have fun.